# UIPickerView separator line missing in iOS9.3

Tags: ios, iphone, uipickerview, ios9.3

I am using swift with xcode7.3.1. In my xib file added picker view showing separator lines like the following screenshot

[image]

But when i run app in simulator then missing separator line like the following screenshot.
[image]

How to solve this issue.Please help me

Comment: This is not an issue. If you set you simulator scale to 100% it will look perfect. `window>scale>100%`

Comment: yes you are absolutely right.Thank you

Comment: You can use CMD-S to get a full resolution screenshot from the simulator without having to change the scale. It will save to your desktop so you can see exactly what it will look like.

Comment: Just add [_pickerDD selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

As answered by  Bhavin Ramani in a comment:

Set your simulator scale to 100%. It should show both lines. In the simulator top menu window > scale > 100%